# Android SQLite SELECT Boolean

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have problems to make the query, I think the problem is the structure of the query
this is the class to do the select

```
 public boolean buscarCONTACTO (int id, String nom, int tlf, String email){
            boolean result = false;
            String nombretaula ="contactos";
            SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
          try{
                String QUERY = "SELECT "+ id +","+ nom +","+ tlf +","+ email +" FROM " + nombretaula ;
                Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(QUERY, null);
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
                    if(cursor.getString(0).equalsIgnoreCase("1")){
                        result = true;
                    }
                }
                db.close();
          }catch(Exception e ){

           e.printStackTrace();

            }
            return result;
        }
```

to check whether or not it is in the database that is this (MainActivity)
 [image]
[image]

Comment: Stackoverflow community requires you to post your code in your question and not your code image!

Answer (score 0):

Your +"id"+ and +"tlf"+ is having Int value so wrap it with ' ' this will solve your problem.

```
String QUERY = "SELECT '"+ id +"',"+ nom +",'"+ tlf +"',"+ email +" FROM " + nombretaula ;
```

Happy Coding.

Answer (score 0):

The `SELECT` command is something like:

`SELECT column2_name FROM table_name WHERE column1_name = column1_value`

here you are passing field names as values instead of name. For example, you are passing `id`'s value not it's string. So, your query become something like this:

`SELECT 1,afda,adada FROM asdasd`

your query should be something like this:

`"SELECT nom FROM " + table_name + " WHERE id=" + id`

Answer (score 0):

The arguments `id`, `nom`, `tlf` and `email` in the `buscarCONTACTO()` method are integer or string literals, but you use them in the `SELECT` list as column names.
Also, this method checks only the 1st column of the 1st row returned from the query.
If the names of the columns are also `id`, `nom`, `tlf` and `email` and you want to check whether a row with the arguments you pass exists in the table then do this:

```
public boolean buscarCONTACTO(int id, String nom, int tlf, String email) {
    boolean result = false;
    String nombretaula ="contactos";
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    try{
        String QUERY = "SELECT * FROM " + nombretaula + " WHERE id = ? AND nom = ? AND tlf = ? AND email = ?";
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(QUERY, new String[] {String.valueOf(id), nom, String.valueOf(tlf), email});
        result = cursor.getCount() > 0;
        cursor.close();
    }catch(Exception e ){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    db.close();
    return result;
}
```

I assume `contactos` is the name of the table.

Comment: debugger does not work on the cursor cursor line = db.rawQuery (QUERY, new String [] {String.valueOf (id), nom, String.valueOf (tlf), email});

Comment: What is the message?

Comment: returns false not true ,  
I think it does not do  result = cursor.getCount ()> 0;

Comment: Does your app crash?

Comment: Remove the try/catch block and check if the app crashes. If it does not crash and returns false this means that there is not a row in the table with the id, nom, tlf and email that you pass.

Comment: Yes it works but does not go into the "if" directly goes to the "else"

look at the image i think you understand me

Comment: So as I said this means that the method buscarCONTACTO() returned FALSE. Did you remove the try/catch block? If you removed it and the method returns FALSE then this row that you want to check does not exist in the table.

Comment: You must delete try/catch to see WHY it's not working.